# If matched particular keyword change multiple column values in a table

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, gawk

I have a data in below format:

```
38%,1,0,0   
32%,400,376.61,94.1525   
54%,400,197,49.25   
22%,1,1,100
```

if 2nd colum is equal to 1 then change 2nd 3rd and 4 column to NA

```
38%,NA,NA,NA   
32%,400,376.61,94.1525   
54%,400,197,49.25   
22%,NA,NA,NA
```

I have tried to replace one column first but it is not working:

```
awk -F, '$2==1 {$2="NA"}1' OFS=,
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? It works for me.

Comment: Please edit your post to add the output you get. "Not working" is not precise enough for contributors to help you.

Answer (score 1):

To modify multiple columns, separate the assignments by semicolons:

```
$ awk -F, '$2==1 {$2="NA"; $3="NA"; $4="NA"}1' OFS=, file
38%,NA,NA,NA
32%,400,376.61,94.1525   
54%,400,197,49.25   
22%,NA,NA,NA
```

Comment: or `$2=$3=$4="NA"` or a loop but if what the OP tried to do "isn't working" then I doubt if this will either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below command

```
awk -F "," '$2 == "1" {$2=$3=$4="NA"}1' file
```

output

```
38% NA NA NA
32%,400,376.61,94.1525   
54%,400,197,49.25   
22% NA NA NA
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('file','r')
for i in k:
    j=i.split(",")
    if (j[1] == "1"):
        j[1]=j[2]=j[3]="NA"
        print ",".join(j)

    else:
        print i.strip()
```

output

```
38%,NA,NA,NA
32%,400,376.61,94.1525
54%,400,197,49.25
22%,NA,NA,NA
```